# Automating Responsive Web Design

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have the task of transforming an old website (**500+ pages**) into a responsive design. The website is mainly structured from **tables**.

I will be using the **Bootstrap** grid system and focusing mainly on important pages first.

Is there a way to automate this? Crawl through pages, spot patterns, and replace with bootstrap grid components?

Any help/suggestion on how to best tackle this is much appreciated.

Comment: "Crawl through pages, spot patterns, and replace with bootstrap grid components?" — Yes, that. Except AI is really hard so you generally need to define the patterns yourself.

Comment: This task is like "I have to transform 500+ carriages into veritable cars". Would you really consider doing that, or don't you think it's a better idea to buy 500+ cars instead?

Comment: You will have an endless list of bugs regarding responsive behaviour, bugs on mobile etc ***after*** all the transformation has been done. Alone fixing these bugs will probably take considerably longer than starting from scratch. Let alone the fact that you will still have horribly old, shitty code which is a maintenance hell on its own.

Comment: What about making a new _responsive.css_ file, and including it only on priority pages? So manually going through pages and not breaking the main _styles.css_ for other pages.

Answer (score -2):

unfortunately i think this would be impossible, or let's say full of bugs to achieve, one thing you can do is to wrap your tables with  , which is set by bootstrap and giving all tables and class .table  I think this is the best shot.